# Is it possible to keep the same window for every class in python's tkinter?

Tags: python, class, tkinter, window, root

I am trying to create a program in tkinter which allows me to open an initial window then to keep it throughout all classes used. For example, if I was to create a button in a window then when I click this button, it would exuecute a method that destroys the widget, and then executes a new class that builds a new screen within the same window, such as text opposed to a button.

```
from tkinter import *

class Window1:

    def __init__(self, master):
        self.master = master
        self.label = Button(self.master, text = "Example", command = self.load_new)
        self.label.pack()

    def load_new(self):
        self.label.destroy()
        ## Code to execute next class

class Window2:

    def __init__(self, master):
        self.master = master
        self.label = Label(self.master, text = "Example")
        self.label.pack()

def main():
    root = Tk()
    run = Window1(root)
    root.mainloop()

if __name__ == '__main__':
main()
```

I understand this is less practical, but I am curious. Cheers.

Comment: If you just want additional windows, you can use the `Toplevel` widget. If you want to hide the root object, you can use the `withdraw()` method.

Comment: `Tk()` creates main window and `root` give you access to this window. You can use `root` as argument for `Window2` and has access to main window inside `Window2` - but probably nobody use another class to create `Label` in place of `Button`.

Comment: Does the following answer help? http://stackoverflow.com/a/7557028/7432

Comment: Single window applications with changing contents are common.  As furas said, your names `Window1` and `Window2` are misleading.  `Stage` or `Display` or ??? or 'Intro` and `Main` would be better.. If both are subclasses of Frame, then `Frame1` and `Frame2` would be good.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Tk()` creates main window and variable `root` gives you access to this window. You can use `root` as argument for `Window2` and you will have access to main window inside `Window2`

```
from tkinter import *


class Window1:

    def __init__(self, master):

        # keep `root` in `self.master`
        self.master = master 

        self.label = Button(self.master, text="Example", command=self.load_new)
        self.label.pack()

    def load_new(self):
        self.label.destroy()

        # use `root` with another class
        self.another = Window2(self.master)


class Window2:

    def __init__(self, master):

        # keep `root` in `self.master`
        self.master = master

        self.label = Label(self.master, text="Example")
        self.label.pack()


root = Tk()
run = Window1(root)
root.mainloop()
```

--

Probably nobody use another class to create `Label` in place of `Button` ;)

--

**EDIT:** In this example using names `Window1` and `Windows2` is misleading because there is only one window and two classes which use this window. I would rather use names `FirstOwner`, `SecondOwner`

Comment: Thank you very much. This was the exact answer I was looking for.

Answer (score 0):

Everything is implemented in one Tk class and in this case there always is only one window.

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk


class MainWindow():

    def __init__(self, mainWidget):
        self.main_frame = ttk.Frame(mainWidget, width=300, height=150, padding=(0, 0, 0, 0))
        self.main_frame.grid(row=0, column=0)

        self.some_kind_of_controler = 0

        self.main_gui()

    def main_gui(self):
        root.title('My Window')

        self.main_label_1 = ttk.Label(self.main_frame, text='Object_1')
        self.main_label_1.grid(row=0, column=0)

        self.main_label_2 = ttk.Label(self.main_frame, text='Object_2')
        self.main_label_2.grid(row=1, column=0)

        self.main_label_3 = ttk.Label(self.main_frame, text='Object_3')
        self.main_label_3.grid(row=2, column=0)

        self.setings_button = ttk.Button(self.main_frame, text='Setings')
        self.setings_button.grid(row=0, column=1)
        self.setings_button.bind('<Button-1>', self.setings_gui)

        self.gui_elements = [self.main_label_1,
                             self.main_label_2,
                             self.main_label_3,
                             self.setings_button]

    def setings_gui(self, event):
        self.gui_elements_remove(self.gui_elements)

        root.title('Setings')

        self.main_label_1 = ttk.Label(self.main_frame, text='Object_1')
        self.main_label_1.grid(row=2, column=0)

        self.main_menu_button = ttk.Button(self.main_frame, text='Main menu')
        self.main_menu_button.grid(row=0, column=1)
        self.main_menu_button.bind('<Button-1>', self.back_to_main)

        self.some_kind_of_controler = 1

        self.gui_elements = [self.main_label_1,
                             self.main_menu_button]

    def back_to_main(self, event):
        if self.some_kind_of_controler == 1:
            self.gui_elements_remove(self.gui_elements)
        else:
            pass
        self.main_gui()

    def gui_elements_remove(self, elements):
        for element in elements:
            element.destroy()

def main():
    global root

    root = Tk()
    root.geometry('300x150+50+50')
    window = MainWindow(root)

    root.mainloop()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```